# Android Camera really choppy on Samsung Galaxy Tab with AIR Application

Tags: android, air, camera, galaxy

I'm building an AIR Application for Android devices and I'm using the Camera.

I found a really strange behaviour. When I first start the app and the camera initializes, I get around 1fps(!).

If I then press the home Button and klick on the app icon again, it's all good and I get the full framerate.

This same behaviour also occurs within the Tour de Mobile Flex app when I start the Raw Camera part.

As soon as I press home and then return to the app, everythings fine...

Anybody out there having the same issues and maybe a soulution?

Help is highly apreciated.

Comment: Sorry for double posting, but I still have no solution for this problem.


Anybody out there experiencing the same issue. Maybe someone with an Android Device could try the "Tour de mobile Flex" App available in the Android market and tell me if the Raw Camera Example works fleuntly on your device.


Kind Regards

Comment: Since you asked, I am having the exact same issue as you.  I believe it's more of an Samsung issue than Adobe Air.  Can't be certain though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Adobe AIR that is fixed and soon to be released.
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3357078#3357078

Answer (score 0):

Set `<renderMode>direct</renderMode>` in your app.xml. This configuration solve my problem